# Create method in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make a method in sqlite to create a user, but I want to give him an automatic id , I mean the database automatically will give him an id . How can I write this code ?

> ```
> values.put(KEY_ID, user.getId()); // get id
> ```

```
public void CreateUser(user user){

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, user.getId()); // get id
    values.put(KEY_username, user.getUsername()); // get user name 
    values.put(KEY_password, user.getPassword()); // get password
    values.put(KEY_email, user.getEmail()); // get email

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_user,null,values);

    // 4. close
    db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Remove this line: `values.put(KEY_ID, user.getId()); // get id`

Comment: just remove it ? I need to put a code unstead of it right?

Comment: **NO**. Don't touch the primary key! you defined **_id** as the primary key? then it's automatically autoincrementing and unique.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), any column declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is autoincrementing.

To allow the database to assign a value, don't `put` any `KEY_ID` value into the `ContentValues` object.
The ID is then returned by `insert`.

Comment: ONLY if you don't include the id in your insert statement.. which is the error in his code above.